# XSL Picture in table

Tags: image, xslt

I do read the relevant posts, but my code is still not working. I just want to add a avatar (png) to the players in my table.

My HTML:

```
    <root version="2.0">
      <game>
        <players>
        <nickname>thebeast</nickname>
        <avatar><img src="/img/thebeast.png" height="30" width="30"></img></avatar>
        <sum>220</sum>
        </players>


    <players>
    <nickname>snowman</nickname>
    <avatar><img src="/img/snowman.png" height="30" width="30"></img</avatar>
    <sum>360</sum>
    </players> 

    </game>
</root>
```

My table in xsl:

```
<table align = "center" border="transparent">
    <tr><th>Nr.</th><th>Nickname</th><th>Collected <br/>Points</th></tr>
<xsl:for-each select = "//players">
<xsl:sort select = "sum" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:number value = "position()" format = "1."/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "nickname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select = "sum"/></td>
            <td>
            <img>
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="/img" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </img>
            </td>
         </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: Your input is not well-formed: it contains an unclosed `</img` end-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="/img" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

try:

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="avatar/img/@src" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

or, in short:

```
<img src="{avatar/img/@src}"></img>
```

Or, if you want to preserve the dimensions:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="avatar/img"/>
```

Comment: @BilyanaNikolova Good. Please close the question by accepting the answer.